# Question about Witten 0+1 quantum gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, quantum-gravity, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

I am trying to follow Witten’s article as much as I can.
[What every physicist should know about string theory](https://doi.org/10.1063/PT.3.2980). Physics Today 68 (11), 38–43 (2015); my knowledge is very basic GR and QFT. I am really lost at one of his steps early in the article.

As I understand it, he writes an action with variable metric and free massive scalar fields $X_i$. From here he obtains the field equations for the system, which resembles a wave equation. So far, so good. The next step is the one that gets me lost. He introduces a wavefunction $Ψ(X)$, and he makes the former equation an operator that acts on the wavefunction.

Q1: Where does this wave function come from?

Q2: We know that relativistic wave functions only make sense if you consider them as fields, is this a new field? But if so, how do you interpret the KG equation, is it a field (the initial  $X_i$’s) acting on another field $Ψ(X)$? (not sure this interpretation makes any sense).

Comment: My unsolicited advice is not to use that article to study. I think it is more intended as a high level summary of some interesting results, but it's not pedagogical and doesn't really explain the details. If you're interested in string theory, a good introduction (that also covers the "0+1" dimensional case right at the beginning of Chapter 1) is Tong's string theory notes: https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I was trying to peek at the good things that I will learn in the future, I will get to string theory in a more serious approach in about 2 years, I hope.

Comment: Even if you aren't ready for the full thing, I at least recommend Section 1.1 of Tong's notes, which describes what Witten is talking about in a bit more detail.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I will, thanks!

Comment: To add to Andrew's comment, [Dan Israël's String Theory lecture notes](https://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~israel/notes.pdf) discuss the 0+1 dimensional case (section 2.1) in more detail than Tong.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Thanks!